# Two separate events with jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a TV simulation where user clicks on the power button and it loads an external HTML file, which is just a video (wrapped inside of a DIV for styling purposes and such) into a TV-image (which is a div with a tv image as the background, to make it look like someone is turning on and watching TV). However, I want to also have the user be able to turn the TV off. Currently I have it successfully where it loads the external html file (which contains the video) when the power button is pressed. I'm needing to know how do I create a "turn off" feature for the same button, and not have that button repeat the "turn ON" function.

I'm guessing I have to make two functions with the button that when turned on will also load a div overlaid ontop of the power button, which will then serve as the element to be clicked to turn OFF the TV with a separate jquery or JS fucntion? Since if I hit the power button again it will just repeat the turn on function?

I'm really looking for the theory so I can know what and how I have to do it, but here is the current jQuery that is turning the TV on.

```
$("#switch").on("click",function(){
    $("#broadcast").load("shows.html");
});
```

It is important that the user thinks that the power button is turning the TV on and off, even if some overlay or invisible element is placed on top of the power button by virtue of the first/initial onclick.

Comment: Alex's answer would do for your situation. One click event is enough, and just check the flag whether the TV is currently "on" or "off"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use a variable to store the "state" of whether the tv is on or not:

```
var tvOn = false;
$("#switch").on("click", function () { 
    var $el = $('#broadcast');

    if (tvOn) {
        $el.empty();
    }
    else {
        $el.load("shows.html");
    }

    tvOn = !tvOn;
});
```

Or, if the `shows.html` file is static content, you could load it once to begin with then show/hide the container when the button is clicked:

```
var $el = $('#broadcast');
$el.load("shows.html");

$("#switch").on("click", function () {
    $el.toggle();
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly! 
Now I have to figure a way to get it to work on mobile since auto play on vid doesnt work for mobile and it will launch that separate video player instead of play right on the screen.

Comment: Further reading on [Finite-state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will actually work, but I assume it will.

```
$("#switch").on("click",function(){
    $("#broadcast").toggle().load("shows.html");
});
```

Simply added a `toggle()` method between, so it toggles it. However, it will still play the video in the background and so on. It takes a lot more of your code, to really understand what else you got going on.

Comment: I thought about this before but yes the video (really the audio) has to be off when the TV is "off". Thanks for the response and thought though

Comment: @teccnickle Yeah I assumed that's what you wanted. Then you'd have to empty the element (which Alex showed a great example of above my answer) before it also stops the TV. Good luck on the project!